# Zustand state update causing entire app to re-render

Tags: reactjs, next.js, zustand

I've got a next.js app where global state is managed with zustand (with multiple stores). I'm encountering a pesky situation where updating state in one store (controlling modal behaviour) is resulting in a re-render, which then causes a separate store (controlling bottom sheet behaviour) to reset its state.

This leads to unwanted UI behaviour, where the modal closing causes the bottom sheet to close as well (the bottom sheet is meant to stay open).

I can provide some code snippets if needs be. But straight off the bat, I'd appreciate any advice please on how to set up the stores so they stop interfering with each other in this way.

Thanks!

I've tried using the right selector pattern in zustand, and also the useShallow function, but it's not solving the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.